# Input not being accepting on first try

Tags: python

Not sure why even when the entry is correct I still get the error message before it accepts the correct input.

```
even_num=int(input("Please enter a even number from 1-20: "))

while even_num != "2" and even_num !="4" and even_num != "6" and even_num != '8' and 
even_num != '10' and even_num != '12' and even_num != '14' and even_num != '16' and 
even_num != '18' and even_num !='20':
    
    even_num= input( 'Entry invalid.Please enter a even number: ')
print('Entry intput: ',even_num,'Entry Accepted')
```

Comment: what error message?  what are you trying to do?

Comment: You are converting to an int and comparing to a string.

Comment: The first time you assign `even_num`, you have applied `int()` to it - so it cannot possibly be equal to `"2"` or any of the other *strings* you are comparing it to.  The reassignment of `even_num` inside the loop omits the `int()`, so it's now possible to enter a matching string.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and always post "the error message" you got. It helps us to spot the error and explain it, or even guide you interpreting the error-message.

Comment: The code currently shown in your question isn't valid Python — it causes a`SyntaxError: invalid syntax` because you cannot split the `while` condition up over multiple lines like that. Is that what the error message says?

Answer (score 1):

The following will check entries for validity and accept valid ones on the first try:

```
while True:
    try:
        even_num = int(input("Please enter an even number from 1-20: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, please enter an integer value.\n")
        continue

    if not 1 <= even_num <= 20:
        print("Sorry, your response was not in the range of 1-20.\n")
        continue
    elif even_num % 2 != 0:
        print("Sorry, your response must be an even number.\n")
        continue
    else:
        break

print('Entry input: ', even_num, 'accepted')
```

Answer (score 0):

Without given error-message I can only suggest improvement:

1. simplify the test for even number with `in [2,4]` (compare to a list of integers instead combining string-comparison)
2. extract the test as function and make it defensive/safe (test also for int)
3. improve readability of the loop-condition similar to "ask while input not valid"
4. format strings (use f-string since Python 3.8) and give user a feedback which input was invalid
5. reuse the prompt when asking for input

```
# extract condition to a function
def valid_even_num(number):
    # test for int  and number is even (in valid range)
    if isinstance(number, int) and number in [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
        return True
    else
        return False


# can reuse the prompt
prompt = "Please enter an even number from 1-20: "

# following input returned to n can also be a string 
n = input(prompt)

# test what happens if no number is entered. Does int(n) raise an error?
while not valid_even_num(int(n)):
    print(f"Entry '{n}' is invalid!\n")
    n = input(prompt)

print(f"Entry {n} accepted.")
```

For advanced **input-retries** see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).
The answer there explains the same pattern that [Martineau answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72312336/5730279): `while True: try/except/continue`.